# How to catch the process took 100% cpu?

Tags: security, centos, cpu

My server had no response at about 12:30AM last night. I found it this morning, and even cannot ssh into it. Network monitor told me my CPU usage is 100%. The only thing I can do is to hard reboot it. After reboot, everything seems ok now.

But I think the potential issue is still there, because I don't know which process had taken such a high CPU usage last night.

Is there anyway I can find out the history CPU usage by process? Or if not, what can I do to prevent, or at least monitor and know it?

I am thinking of save the "top" command result every minute into files, so maybe I can catch it, but maybe there is other better ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options - first, you can start a periodic CRON script that will check the overall CPU usage every minute or every 5 minutes. The overall CPU usage of the system can be determined using either of following commands:
top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" |  sed "s/.*, *([0-9.]*)%* id.*/\1/" |  awk '{print 100 - $1}'
OR
mpstat | grep -A 5 "%idle" | tail -n 1 | awk -F " " '{print 100 -  $13}'a

The script should get the CPU usage and should check if the CPU usage exceeds a threshold, like 75%. If this scenario happens, the script can dump the output of top command (top -b -n 2) in a file.

The second option is to use some open source monitoring tool like monit (https://mmonit.com/monit/). Monit can be used to monitor the system CPU usage and it can also be programmed to take an action if CPU usage exceeds a threshold.

Comment: The first option is cool, because I want to know exactly which process took the most CPU. Thank you!